# flutter websocket chat ui

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

Im trying to use flutter websocket in flutter chat ui package anyone has experience?

```
              messages: _messages,
              onAttachmentPressed: _handleAtachmentPressed,
              onMessageTap: _handleMessageTap,
              onPreviewDataFetched: _handlePreviewDataFetched,
              onSendPressed: _handleSendPressed,
              showUserAvatars: true,
              showUserNames: true,
              user: _user,
            ),
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to set websocket in this package.
Can you help me?